# TransactionAbortedException - can you safely re-run?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using `TransactionScope` in the following fashion

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var conn = SQLHelpers.GetSQLConnection())
    {  
          //commands here
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Sometimes I am getting an `TransactionAbortedException` when calling `scope.Complete()` as the transaction has already been rolled back and I have used the profiler to determine the issue is a deadlock.

> Exception  Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I've since found the cause for the deadlock however it got me wondering why this error did not bubble up to the `TransactionAbortedException` so I could indeed re-run the transaction just for that specific case. *The inner exception(s) did NOT contain any information that could indicate what the actual error was.*

**Is it safe to detect a `TransactionAbortedException` as the reason to re-run the transaction?**

Up to now I've seen the following inner exceptions:

1) deadlock
2) timeout
3) 'connection was closed'
4) .. other ?

in only 1 of these cases it seems appropriate to re-run the transaction however you could generalize this to all cases if you were guaranteed a rollback. The question could be re-stated to ask 'does a TransactionAbortedException guarantee the transaction was rolled back' ?

Comment: Do you see InnerException of the TransactionAbortedException is a timeout?

Comment: no the only `InnerException` is :`The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.` and I am getting this because I call `scope.Complete` when the transaction has been rolled back by the deadlock

Comment: Try this if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed) 
{
    scope.Complete();
}

Comment: for what purpose? to stop it blowing up? that will avoid the Exception but you'll never know your data didnt save

Comment: so if its not committed , it means not saved

Comment: If its deadlock, then transaction is merely aborted to resolve it, which is a standard deadlock resolving mechanism. You will be better off debugging deadlock using windbg or try `CommittableTransaction`, if anything else crops up, which I doubt. Also check if you can reduce the isolation level to avoid deadlock scope.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj ok you get a `TransactionAbortedException` - what could be the cause of that ? just a deadlock or many other things?

Comment: @wal reasons can be manifold, a simple exception will cause it, Not sure if the real exception details shall be filled in the inner exception.
Though can be checked, but a deadlock resolution causing exception and not filling the inner exception is quite feasible as there's nothing much to inform the user, that's the internal mechanism.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj there-in lies the problem - if you dont know it was as the result of a deadlock you don't know whether to re-run the transaction

Comment: According Microsoft documentation this Exception is launched after the transaction has already been rolled back. I'm not sure you can get the error cause.Maybe evaluating TransactionStatus before calling .Comlete();
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @wal, are you saying, that if transaction was rolled back due to deadlock you want to re-run it, but if transaction was rolled back due to some other reason you don't want to re-run it? In both cases transaction didn't complete, but you want to retry it only in case of a deadlock... My point is, if the nature of the transaction is such that it makes sense to retry it, then I'd retry it in any case, if it failed. This doesn't answer your question how to extract the roll back reason from the C# exception. To do that, I'd use `TRY ... CATCH` in T-SQL and log `ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_MESSAGE()`, etc.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov no not asking abuot deadlocks specifically - am asking whether there are any (db) side effects to re-running (e.g. re-inserting twice) whatever you just ran when you encounter a `TransactionAbortedException` - will update q slightly

Comment: I think it should be a good idea to create a Transaction object and add it to the TransactionScope. (TransactionScope(Transaction)). You can check it after every sql command to know when or why you're getting a deadlock. (Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping command with try / catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 1205)
    {
        // Deadlock 
    }
    else
        throw;
}. The other errors look like transient errors and could be handled by using the Transient Fault Handling Application block

Comment: @SteveFord thanks, do you have a good link to *code* examples using  the Transient Fault Handling Application block?

Answer (score 3):

> The question could be re-stated to ask 'does a
>   TransactionAbortedException guarantee the transaction was rolled
>   back'?

The documentation for [`TransactionAbortedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionabortedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> This exception is thrown when an action is attempted on a transaction
>   that **has already been rolled back**, for example, when you attempt to
>   call the `Commit` method on a transaction that has already timed out.
>   This exception is also thrown when an attempt is made to commit the
>   transaction and the transaction aborts.
>
> This is a recoverable error.

I think it is pretty clear from this description that if you catch this exception, your transaction didn't complete successfully due to some reason. My understanding of the docs is: "Whatever changes the transaction was trying to do were not committed to the database".

"This is a recoverable error", so if the nature of your transaction is such that it makes sense to retry it, then you should retry it after catching this exception.

You may want to introduce some logic around retries, such as waiting for some time before retry. And increase this waiting time as the number of retry attempts increases. Have a limit on the total amount of retries or total retry time and do something sensible/fail gracefully when all attempts to retry failed.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the question, but I am working on similar issue.

There are a few things that you need to consider

1. is this part of nested transaction.
2. might it be in the future.
3. are there any asynchronous transactions being run.

If an inner transaction is rerun , the state of the outerscope transaction
Might have already been compromised.  Pretty easy to test.

1. Create nested transaction,
2. during debug stop at inner transaction.
3. go to sql server and run some query to lock the table used by inner transaction.
4. run inner transaction and wait for deadlock.
5. after TransactionAboted Exception is received, go back to sql server and release lock.
6. loop back and rerun inner transaction.
7. check inner transaction status.
8. check state of outer transaction before trying to commit outer transaction.